# How do I improve the efficiency of big dict conversion to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```py
my_data = {
    'col': "{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'e': 5}",
    'col2': "{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'e': 5}"
}
index = list('abcd')
```

## function one

```py
my_dict = {}
for col in ['col', 'col2']:
    print(my_data[col])
    my_dict[col] = eval(my_data[col])
# it takes two seconds
print(pd.DataFrame(my_dict, index=index))
```

## function two

The most time-consuming part is creating the series

```py
list_data = []
# for loop takes two seconds
for col in ['col', 'col2']:
    list_data.append(pd.Series(eval(my_data[col]), index=index, name=col))
# takes tens of milliseconds
print(pd.concat(list_data, axis=1, copy=False))
```

I have a big dict, it takes two seconds to convert to a dataframe, is there any way to improve it?

Comment: `dict create is in loop` - how looks loop?

Comment: Does it take two seconds to convert the dict to a dataframe, or does it take two seconds to create the dict with that for loop? You probably want to share and refine that for-loop part.

Comment: @jezrael change my QA, it might have been confusing before

Comment: @Tarquinius  change my QA, it might have been confusing before

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` in the following way

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

my_data = {
    'col': "{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'e': 5}",
    'col2': "{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'e': 5}"
}
index = list('abcd')

my_dict = {}
for col in ['col', 'col2']:
    my_dict[col] = ast.literal_eval(my_data[col])

df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict, index=index)
print(df)
```